# Intellij / Pycharm: Credentials mismatch while pushing to private remote github repo

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have two accounts on github: `account1` and `account2`.

I am trying to push to a private remote repo (`repo2`) on github that has write access for `account2`. However, I keep getting the error message: `Failed with Error: repository 'remote@github.com' not found`.

This is because it is not able to authenticate the credentials for `account2`. I am able to push fine through commandline: `git push https://account2:password@github.com/repo master`

If I do the same thing of `account1` for a repository (`repo1`) that has write access for `account1` then everything works fine. Interestingly, if I give write access to `account1` on `repo2`, then also push goes through. This means, pycharm has somehow **hardwired** `account1` credentials in it.

- The username-password in preferences in pycharm is set to `account2`.
- I found this blog post: http://danielhnyk.cz/pycharm-error-fatal-could-not-read-remote-repository/, that suggests that for remote push/pull pycharm uses the default ssh credentials `isa_pub`. I tried replacing the default `isa_pub` with the ssh-key for `account2`, but that also didn't help.

**tl;dr Question:**  Two github accounts, two different private repos. How do I configure pycharm to use repo specific user credentials to allow remote push/pull?

Using pycharm 2016.3.2 on OS XY 10.10.4

In Addition: `account1` doesn't even have a ssh authentication setup with github, still pycharm defaults to use credentials for `account1`

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you need here is support of several GitHub accounts, which is not possible atm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82222

If you just want to change one account to another, note, that IDE replies on the command line git client. It seems like command line git client cached credentials on its own and uses accoutn1 for all connections to GitHub. You could try totally disabling git credential helper on the repository and check if the issue stays.